# Why my python code terminates even though I have proper exception handling?

Tags: python, exception, subprocess

I have the following python code:

```
try:
    subprocess.check_output('service uwsgi stop;pkill -f uwsgi', shell = True)
except:
    sys.exit(0)
```

it should return always 0 but when I run it, it prints 'Terminated' and then I receive a non-zero return code.

Comment: Are you sure it's raising an exception or just printing it out?

Comment: What is the rest of your code?  How do you know that section is causing the problem?  With that code, it will just continue on and execute whatever comes next in your file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now, `sys.exit(0)` will only be called when an exception is raised. To ensure that it is called every time, add a finally statement:

```
try:
    subprocess.check_output('service uwsgi stop;pkill -f uwsgi', shell = True)
except:
    # Handle the exception
finally:
    sys.exit(0)
```